# TYPO3 TCA userfunc

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

Kinda stuck.

We have products which we offer to companies.
so it would be an mm field which is no problem to implement, but the problem comes with date, since each product has expire date based on company.

so decided to remove product mm and put product id with date into company as one field.

but since input which we send is an array it's not possible to save it there.

How can i solve this problem ?
this is my tca for that field:

```
'product' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:wemessage_checklist/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_wemessagechecklist_domain_model_company.product',
    'config' => [
       'type' => 'user',
       'userFunc' => Wemessage\WemessageChecklist\UserFunc\Checklist::class.'->renderChecklists',               
    ],
],
```

Here is function to render html:

```
public function renderChecklists($PA, $fObj){
    $checked = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTgetRows('*', 'tx_wemessagechecklist_domain_model_company', 'hidden=0 and deleted=0 and uid='.$PA['row']['uid'].' and pid='.$PA['row']['pid']);
    $allProducts = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTgetRows('*', 'tx_wemessagechecklist_domain_model_product', 'hidden= 0 and deleted = 0');
    foreach($allProducts as $product){
        $html .= '<div>';
        $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="data[tx_wemessagechecklist_domain_model_company]['.$PA['row']['uid'].'][product]['.$product['uid'].']" class="product"/>';
        $html .= '<input type="checkbox" class="tocheck" value="'.$product['uid'].'" /><span style="margin: 0 10px;">'.$product['name'].'</span><span style="margin: 0 10px;">Verval datum</span><input type="date" class="date" />';
        $html .= '</div>';
    }
    $html .= '<script>
        TYPO3.jQuery(".tocheck").click(function(){
            var val = TYPO3.jQuery(this).val();
            if(TYPO3.jQuery(this).prop("checked")){
                TYPO3.jQuery(this).parent().find(".product").val(val);
            }
        });
        TYPO3.jQuery(".date").change(function(){
            var x = new Date(TYPO3.jQuery(this).val()).getTime();
            var b = TYPO3.jQuery(this).parent().find(".product").val();
            TYPO3.jQuery(this).parent().find(".product").val(b+":"+x);
        });
        </script>';
    return $html;
}
```

probably another option is to implement AJAX calls to process data in standalone table. although if there is another solution will be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

You should still go for an MM relation or better inline (IRRE) connection from company to product, since these can have an own TCA too, thus making it possible to add starttime, endtime and other values to the MM relation record itself.

The concept is called "intermediate table" and is described here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline.html#attributes-on-anti-symmetric-intermediate-table

Here is a modified TCA taken from the IRRE tutorial extension. It contains just the necessary settings for the connections and the timestamp field - feel free to add your own fields for companies and products:

```
$TCA["company"] = Array (
    "columns" => Array (
        "products" => Array (
            "config" => Array (
                "type" => "inline",
                "foreign_table" => "company_product_intermediate",
                "foreign_field" => "company_id",
                "foreign_sortby" => "companysort",
                "foreign_label" => "product_id",
                "maxitems" => 10,
                'appearance' => array(
                    'showSynchronizationLink' => 1,
                    'showAllLocalizationLink' => 1,
                    'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => 1,
                    'showRemovedLocalizationRecords' => 1,
                ),
                'behaviour' => array(
                    'localizationMode' => 'select',
                ),
            )
        ),
    ),
);



$TCA["company_product_intermediate"] = Array (
    "columns" => Array (
        "company_id" => Array (
            "config" => Array (
                "type" => "select",
                "foreign_table" => "company",
                "maxitems" => 1,
            )
        ),
        "product_id" => Array (
            "config" => Array (
                "type" => "select",
                "foreign_table" => "product",
                "maxitems" => 1,
            )
        ),
        "companysort" => Array (
            "config" => Array (
                "type" => "passthrough",
            )
        ),
        "productsort" => Array (
            "config" => Array (
                "type" => "passthrough",
            )
        ),
        "timestamp" => Array (
            "config" => Array (
                "type" => "input",
            )
        ),
    ),
);



$TCA["product"] = Array (
    "columns" => Array (
        "companies" => Array (
            "config" => Array (
                "type" => "inline",
                "foreign_table" => "company_product_intermediate",
                "foreign_field" => "product_id",
                "foreign_sortby" => "productsort",
                "foreign_label" => "company_id",
                "maxitems" => 10,
                'appearance' => array(
                    'showSynchronizationLink' => 1,
                    'showAllLocalizationLink' => 1,
                    'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => 1,
                    'showRemovedLocalizationRecords' => 1,
                ),
                'behaviour' => array(
                    'localizationMode' => 'select',
                ),
            )
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Wel if we use inline and mm we get thousands of products.

this is really not good solution not for us.

complete that part with AJAX. added table to serve as MM + inline so instead of thousands of products we have just 6 products and each of those can be assigned to company with it's own time.

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote before: The connection has to be done using 3 tables: Company, Product and the intermediate inline table defining the connection between companies and products. So the only table getting thousands of entries is the intermediate table, but that's exactly the job of MM or inline tables within a normalized database. And within this table you can manage starttime and endtime for each particular connection when you assign an own TCA configuration to it. Basically inline with intermediate tables is just a specific form of MM connection.

Comment: Product,  Company + MM means 3 tables.

You can't add extra fields to MM table or  i'm not aware of such. 
so each time you add product with date it will create new product with specified date.

Comment: Please read the article I have linked in my original answer.
1. You can add TCA to almost any table even MM tables
2. You can make use of a special MM table variant called "intermediate table", that is described in the article. 
Intermediate tables are more convenient, since they don't have to use "uid_local" or "uid_foreign" but like in the article can have fields like "company" and "person".
Making use of TCA you can add more fields. In the example it's "jobtype", but it can be starttime or endtime too. And since they are "inline" you can edit them within the form of the parent record.

Comment: You can see the results of intermediate tables with TCA in this tutorial. https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/irre_tutorial/Manual/Index.html#attributes-for-each-m-n-relation  even though the screenshots are quite old, I think they still show, how the concept works.

Comment: from what i'm understanding you suggesting this model:

`    'config' => [
                'type' => 'inline',
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_testext_domain_model_product',
                'foreign_field' => 'company',
`
which will give us:
https://ibb.co/dae9he

and that is completely not what i need. since this model will gives us thousands products.

this is what we need: https://ibb.co/frPH2e

Comment: You still don't get the concept - so plz read the documentation again.

Intermediate table would be tx_testext_domain_model_product_company and it connects both - products AND companies - as kind of an extended MM table having 2 fields, namely product AND company.

So tx_testext_domain_model_company would get that as foreign inline table via the company field while tx_testext_domain_model_product would be connected via product. Additionally you can have other fields in the TCA of tx_testext_domain_model_product_company to enrich the connection with additional data like starttime or endtime

Comment: Another nice side effect of that approach is, that you can create and edit the records of the intermediate table directly in the backend. So you can even have editors easily create connections between companies and products without being allowed to edit records of the company or product tables themselves.

Comment: Jo , this is not what we want, we do not want to edit intermediate table in backend like you are suggesting. we need to edit company and add products with dates....

with ajax calls which we have implemented, we are editing that intermediate table, but from company perspective.

I was asking if there was some solution to edit company  and add products with dates without using ajax.

Comment: You still don't get the point. With the intermediate table you get EXACTLY what you are asking for. First create some PRODUCTS and store them in the PRODUCTS  table. Now create or edit a COMPANY in the COMPANY table and while doing that add INLINE records of the INTERMEDIATE table to the PRODUCTS field of the COMPANY table. Those inline records connect the company with as many products as you like. Still the number of records in the product table stays the same. Since the intermediate table has got other fields and a TCA for these fields, you can add the timestamp there too.